# Reading Cassandra Map in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I have table created using map in cassandra, Now i am trying to read the table from node.js and it returns object for the map, can i get the item count in a map and loop through it to get the items in the map?

table script
create table workingteam (teamid bigint primary key, status map)

Comment: If you are using the native driver, maps are mapped into javascript objects. So you could something like `for (var key in mapObject) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You did not post a lot of details. First you will need to study the object Cassandra sends you. Good way to start would be to convert it to the JSON format and dump to the output through log.

```
console.log("Cassandra sent: %j", object);
```

I'm guessing in this object you will find attributes like connection parameters, host, client etc, but also something iterative that will contain keys and values.